# How do I fix my Panasonic DMC-FZ35 from releasing the shutter on a half-press?

Tags: troubleshooting, shutter, panasonic-lumix

I have an older Panasonic Lumix (DMC FZ35) that has worked well for 7 years. Today I found that every time I half-pressed the shutter button to focus, it took the picture without letting me compose or focus (it did attempt to autofocus on something before shooting, it just didn't let me adjust my aim or anything). This happened on full automatic, partial manual, and full manual settings. Searching has turned up a few similar issues but usually with new cameras and the advice is return it. That is not possible in my case.

I already did a factory reset in case some setting had gotten messed up.
Any suggestions for solving this problem? Or advice on how to live with it if I can't? A new camera is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Can't you have the camera checked ?  hardware can fail, maybe it is a simple solution (cleaning the contacts...) that a technician can do ?

Comment: I will try to find someone, it's not that easy to find people who fix cameras though (I'm in the Caribbean) everyone replaces rather than repairs these days.

Comment: I have the same issue...did u get any resolution?

Answer (score 2):

In my Lumix I have function in menu: "Half Press Release".  If you have it in menu, check if it is on/off.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Lumix FZ82 and after several attempts I found out what I believe to be the correct set of Settings to check/change. You can see them in the pictures. Hope it helps.[image][image]